# How to Restart/Reload an Activity whenever it is opened?

Tags: android

My question is how do i restart my whole activity whenever it is opened. For example, in my activity I use a timer. If I open another screen and then I come back to it, I want the whole activity to be restated. I have seen on the Android Developers site that I have to use the onStop() and onStart() methods, but please can someone explain how I would do this and where i would place the code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain why you want this?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want Activity2 to be restarted whenever you are going from Activity1 to Activity2.
You can do this:

in Activity1:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("item", 1);
    startActivity(i);
```

in Activity2:

```
Intent i=getIntent();
int item=i.getIntExtra("item", 0);
```

By this you will know if you came to Activity2 from Activity1 (item=1) or just restarted Activity2 (item=0).
Now you can easily put an if condition in onResume() or simply in onCreate method.

```
if(item==1)
{
 Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
 startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restart activity with this method

```
 public void restartActivity() {
    this.finish();
    this.startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

When you call this method in the activity it will restart itself.

Comment: Interesting answer here, never seen it before.